# Python: Why does my discord bot print multiple outputs for a single command? Additionally, how do I restart/shut down my bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm really new to python and relatively inexperienced in coding in general, so this is something I can't really work out on my own.

The bot didn't duplicate the outputs the first few times I tried running the commands, but it started multiplying the outputs after I added more number of commands. I also cut and paste a bunch of code lines around, but nothing gave me an error in my text editor (Atom).

Also, how do I easily restart my bot? I'm using Atom, I don't see an obvious way of doing that on it...

Here's the code I used (all that's left is the token in the end):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():

       print("Hello world")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined a server')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left a server')


@client.command()
async def moon(ctx):
    await ctx.send('dancer')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')


@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4gvD.png)

[Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIPHR.png)

I appreciate all input from everyone, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The bot multiplying the output is most likely a bug because I don't see what you did wrong. I think it may be a problem with your IDE - I don't recommend Atom to run Python scripts you should use VScode or PyCharm - or a problem with your Python interpreter.

To easily shut down the bot, I used this command in my bot:

```
import sys
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.command()
async def quit(ctx):
    sys.exit()

client.run("")
```

After that just run your program again. But the easiest way is to just manually kill your program.

Comment: The multiple output error is getting fixed by just rebooting the bot for some reason. But if I move the code around a bit and then save it and try running any command, it gets buggy again and is returning me the previous output aswell (hence doubling it). I guess I can reboot the bot every time I make changes, but I can't figure out why this bug is occurring.
And I'll try pycharm like you said, thanks for the suggestion! really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way that I can think of to restart your bot is to simply manually stop the python code. I use the [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run) package in atom to run my python code. I simply press F5 to start the code and it open up the console outside of the atom text editor. Stopping my code from there is as simple as closing that window.